# How to Display Data that is Still Being Loaded from Firestore in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to set up the basic user sign up, login ,edit profile, view profile pages. Currently the signup, login and edit profile work fine and i can write to the firestore. However im having some issues with retrieving the data, ive look at the code on how to retrieve data but its not working for my code. I have a user class that gets the users current info and sets some variables to that so that i can only get the info from database once. However, when i try and construct a user inside the profile page class and get the info, what happens is it skips the get info method because its async since the getCurrentUser nested inside is async because the auth.currentuser method needs to be async.

So i understand what the problem is and i tested it out and got values that prove this in the console but how do i fix this? What changes can i make in my code to be able to not skip getting the info before calling to get the info and returning null? I am new to flutter so i am sorry if this may be obvious, any help is greatly appreciated thank you,

Also my code works to get the specific values from the database, so dont worry about that if its not related since it shows up correctly in the console but after being skipped since its async.

These are the methods i mentioned that are present INSIDE the User class:

```
final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  final _auth= FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

Future<void> getCurrentUser() async{
      try{
        final user= await _auth.currentUser();

        if(user!=null){
          loggedInUser=user;
          email=loggedInUser.email;
        }}
      catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
    }

    void getInfo() async {
        await getCurrentUser();
        DocumentReference documentReference =
        _firestore.collection("users").document("$email");
        documentReference.get().then((DocumentSnapshot datasnapshot) {
          if (datasnapshot.exists) {
            displayName=datasnapshot.data['displayName'].toString();
            bio=datasnapshot.data['bio'].toString();
            print(bio);
          }
          else {
            print("No such user");
          }
        });
      }
```

As you can see getCurrentUser needs to be async. I have other variables and methods and constructors but i tried sharing only what needs to be shown.

Then i have this code that is inside the profilepagestate:

```
User currentUser;
  String bio;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    currentUser= new User();
    currentUser.getInfo();
    bio= currentUser.getBio();
  }
```

Then further down the profile page i create a text widget:

```
Text('$bio', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, ))
```

However, the text always shows null on the screen, and i understand whats happening but i dont know how to fix it. I've tried switching things around making something not async or atleast trying but i cant figure it out. Please do not delete my post, ive looked around and this question is specific to my code i really do not know how to fix this i just dont want to waste any more time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show an alternative widget (commonly a loading indicator) while the data is still loading.

```
return bio == null
  ? CircularProgressIndicator()
  : Text('$bio', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, ));
```

---

**UPDATE**

Your loading indicator stucks because your page never gets rebuilt when the data is loaded. You need to rebuild the page by calling `setState` when the currentUser data is done loading.

```
@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  currentUser= new User();
  currentUser.getInfo().then((_) => 
    setState(() => bio = currentUser.getBio()));
}
```

To be able to chain the `async` call, you need to switch the return value of `getInfo()` from `void` to `Future<void>`.

```
Future<void> getInfo() async {
  await getCurrentUser();
  // ..
}
```

Comment: Ohhh, wait where do i add that? i can't use a return where i create my widgets or an if statement checking it its null

Comment: You should add that where you initialise your `Text` widget. Just ignore the `return`.

Comment: Okay i did that but the spinner is just spinning forever even though the value of bio was printed in the console like seconds after reaching the page? Its been spinning for a few mins and still nothing , why do you think that is

Comment: I get this when i try everything you said, error:                                                   `The argument type '() → void' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(void) → FutureOr<dynamic>'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [funder] lib\profilepage.dart:21)

Comment: Sorry, it should be `currentUser.getInfo().then((_) => setState(() => bio = currentUser.getBio()));`

Comment: Its still spinning endlessly, even after printing the value seconds from going to the page.

Comment: Can you print the value of `bio` inside `setState(() => bio = currentUser.getBio())`? It can be because of many reasons. You know it works if the value of `bio` is not `null` inside the `setState`

Comment: well i cant print it inside since it only expects one argument. But when i print it directly after it prints null then the actual bio is printed in the console AFTER so we're getting the same problem, since the second print is from the getInfo method and its getting the info after

Comment: `setState(() {
  bio = currentUser.getBio();
  print(bio);
});`

Comment: Okay it still prints null and then the bio from the getInfo print

Comment: Yes, so this is another issue. You need to track why `currentUser.getBio()` still returns `null` even after calling `currentUser.getInfo()`

Comment: The getBio is a simple getter method, I dont think getBio is the issue, the issue is that getInfo is occuring or getting the information AFTER we can getBio which is what im asking how to solve. How do i wait for getInfo to retrieve all the data and THEN getBio. I dont think the method we used works to solve that evidently

Comment: I'm certain this line of code `currentUser.getInfo().then(() ..` calls `getInfo()` before calling `getBio()`. Can you put breakpoints on both method to check which gets executed first?

Comment: what do you mean breakpoints how do i do that? Well yea i think that method should be doing that but what about the underscore we added could that alter its functionality?